# Visa for Peru for Indian National in Bolivia or Argentina?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, peru

I am an Indian travelling to Argentina and Bolivia. Can I get a visa for Peru from the Consulate of Peru at Buenos Aires or La Paz?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to go to the Peruvian Embassy in Buenos Aires.

The cost of a tourist visa should be US$30, and it should take at least 24 hours (can probably pay more to get an express one).

Requirement for Peru visa application:
Those requiring a tourist visa must provide:

- Valid passport
- Evidence of departure arrangements from Peru
- 2 colour passport-size photos
- Proof of financial solvency
- 2 completed application forms

The address for the embassy: [Peruvian Embassy Av.del Libertador 1720 1425, Buenos Aires](http://goo.gl/maps/HP9qz)

([source](http://www.smiletravelvietnam.com/peru-embassy-in-buenos-aires))